# Errors trying to install perl Image::Magick module on macOS, ventura, 13.2 (Intel machine)

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I have imagemagick installed with brew as well as opencl-headers. Trying to install perl's Image::Magick module running on Perl 5.36, I get the following errors running `cpanm Image::Magick`:

```
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (7.64)
Checking if you have parent 0 ... Yes (0.238)
Building and testing Image-Magick-v7.0.11 ... cp Magick.pm blib/lib/Image/Magick.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Image/Magick.pm (blib/lib/auto/Image/Magick)
Running Mkbootstrap for Magick ()
chmod 644 "Magick.bs"
"/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Magick.bs blib/arch/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bs 644
"/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl" "/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp"  -typemap '/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/ExtUtils/typemap' -typemap '/Users/steve/.cpanm/work/1675177488.60361/Image-Magick-7.0.11/typemap'  Magick.xs > Magick.xsc
mv Magick.xsc Magick.c
cc -c  -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/usr/include/ImageMagick-7" -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -mmacosx-version-min=12.5 -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -I/usr/include/freetype2 -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration -O3   -DVERSION=\"7.0.11\" -DXS_VERSION=\"7.0.11\"  "-I/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/darwin-2level/CORE"  -D_LARGE_FILES=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H Magick.c
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib" cc -Wl,-rpath,"/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib" -L/usr/local/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI  -mmacosx-version-min=12.5 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector-strong   Magick.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle  \
           -L/usr/local/lib -lMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI -lm -L/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/lib/5.36.0/darwin-2level/CORE   \

ld: warning: -undefined dynamic_lookup may not work with chained fixups
ld: warning: dylib (/usr/local/lib/libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (13.0) than being linked (12.5)
chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bundle
Manifying 1 pod document
"/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' -- Magick.bs blib/arch/auto/Image/Magick/Magick.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/Users/steve/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/blob.t .......... ok
t/composite.t ..... ok
t/filter.t ........ ok
t/getattribute.t .. ok
t/montage.t ....... ok
t/ping.t .......... ok
t/read.t .......... ok
t/setattribute.t .. ok
t/write.t ......... Failed 1/32 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/write.t       (Wstat: 0 Tests: 32 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  24
Files=9, Tests=273,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.02 sys +  4.10 cusr  0.56 csys =  4.74 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/9 test programs. 1/273 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
FAIL
```

Also seem to be having issues

Comment: You didn't show the command you used - only the output?

Comment: cpanm Image::Magick

Answer (score 2):

Based on the name of the test that was failing:

`t/write.t ......... Failed 1/32 subtests`

It seems like the problem was likely some kind of permission issue. So I did "cpanm --force Image::Magick". After installing, my Perl script which uses ImageMagick works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Without wishing in the slightest to disparage the work of any of the good folk who port and maintain packages for us, I note the following:

- there are just 37 questions tagged [perlmagick](/questions/tagged/perlmagick) on **StackOverflow**, versus 9,000+ on **ImageMagick** - so your chances of support/assistance are distinctly lower with **Perl**
- Apple has stated its intention to discontinue **Perl**, **PHP** and other interpreters in the next **macOS** version and it is getting more difficult with each **macOS** release to use **ImageMagick** with **PHP** and **Perl**.

---

Given the above, I would personally think twice about investing a large amount of effort into **PerlMagick** on **macOS** - especially when you consider that it is very simple to use **docker** and if you go that way, you can run your **docker** image on any macOS or Linux machine without worrying about the vagaries of the distribution. So, here is a very simple way to run **PerlMagick** in **docker**:

```
docker run -it alpine                                  # 2 seconds later
apk update && apk add perl imagemagick-perlmagick      # 8 seconds later

# All ready to run PerlMagick - let's test a simple example
perl -MImage::Magick -le 'print Image::Magick->QuantumDepth'
16
```

Of course, you can put the two `apk` package management commands into a Dockerfile so they are built-in and don't need running each time.

You can also dynamically bind-mount any **macOS** directory full of images to process into the docker image so that it can read/write them.

Comment: Didn't seem to have anything to do with headers. Some kind of permissions problem, looks like, basied on the failing test. Using --force worked.