# ImageMagick: Place a label in the center of a white splotch

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I have a big black canvas. I then read a sequence of images, same size as the canvas. They're mostly black, but each has a single, white splotch. I composite all these splotches in the single big image. The splotches don't overlap. I want to place a label in the center of each white splotch, but I don't know how to determine the coordinates of the center of a splotch. I could use a Trim on each individual splotch image, to get the bounding box of the splotch and find its center. But this doesn't give me the offset to properly place the label in the big image. How can I do this? I use an old version of IM (6.8.9) with Perl (5.16), but I don't think it matters.

[image]

Comment: Your Imagemagick version is too old to use connectected components processing to find the centroids. So the only way you have is to find each white region and get the bounding boxes. You can do that with my multicrop script, I think. That is you can crop each region. Or you can program that yourself by searching your image in a grid pattern finding white and flood filling everything else with black. Then trim to the bounding box.

Comment: Just checked and -connected-components was available for Imagemagick 6.8.9.10 or later. See https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php. Give that a try or let me know if you need help and provide your input image without the labels.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks, I'll try "Connected Components". I use an older version, because I don't want to break my older Perl scripts.

Comment: Just a thought if you are worried about breaking Perl scripts https://stackoverflow.com/a/75300510/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032739/2836621

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point about each region coming in in it own image. I thought you had all the white regions in one image and needed to separate them.  Mark Setchell's solution below is a good one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your splotches arrive, individually and unlabelled, on a canvas the same size as the image you have shared, they must presumably look like this:

[image]

That means you can get the width, height, x-offset and y-offset like this:

```
read w h x y <(magick Luyti.png -format %@ info: | tr 'x+' ' ')
```

which gives these 4 values:

```
75 93 23 42
```

And then you can calculate the x and y centres with:

```
((cx=x+(w/2)))
((cy=y+(h/2)))
```

which yields 60 and 88 and I have marked with a red circle:

[image]

You can now generate a label and measure its size like this:

```
magick -pointsize 14 -background none -fill blue label:"Label 1" label.png
```

[image]

```
read lw lh < <(magick label.png -format "%w %h" info:)
```

which yields 48 and 17.

Now get the offset to the top left of the label, by subtracting half its width and height from the centre of the splotch:

```
((left=cx-(lw/2)))
((top=cy-(lh/2)))
```

which yields 36 and 80.

Then splat the label on at that offset:

```
magick Luyti.png label.png -geometry +${left}+${top} -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing something else right now, but I'll try this within a few days. If it works (it looks like it will) I'll accept the answer :) Do I need to measure the label? Wouldn't just aligning the text center with the splotch center (Gravity = Center etc) do the job?

Comment: There may be a way of aligning the centres and using gravity - I didn't think of that. I may give it a try when I get back near a computer after the weekend.